# Spring Boot Security and Auth0 - Cannot disable CSRF

Tags: java, spring, security, reactjs, spring-security

I am building a RESTful Spring Boot and React/Alt application. I want to add spring security to make sure that there could be no unauthenticated requests to the API.

I am using Auth0 for an authentication provider so users can log in to the application and more specifically the spring-security-auth0 library to handle the server side security side of things.
https://github.com/auth0/spring-security-auth0

After following the basic tutorial on Auth0, I have configured the security config in my spring application so that requests to the API will not work without a JSON web token. This works, but there are some endpoints (those that need a POST) in the controllers that don't. I get this error in Chrome devtools -

```
Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'
```

I understand that there are no CSRF headers present and that is why it isn't working. But the main reason I am confused is because I have disabled CSRF and it still happens. As the spring docs instruct, I've done this -

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("com.auth0")
@ImportResource("classpath:auth0-security-context.xml")
@PropertySource("classpath:auth0.properties")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
```

I don't need CSRF in this case as the app will only ever be used in a dev environment. Why does this still happen even though I have disabled CSRF completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CsrfFilter that is responsible for the Exception is definetly enabled.
This can have various reasons. Can it be you have another instance of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter configured somewhere ?

You can try the following :

Set a breakpoint in line 'http.csrf().disable();' to see if its really executed.

Set breakpoints in the constructor(s) of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to see whether many instances are created.

This should show you whats going wrong..

Comment: Yeah I had done this, but I am not very familiar with XML configuration in Spring. I decided to convert the Auth0 security context xml into Java Config and disabled CSRF in there. All working now, thanks!